# Regex negative lookahead not excluding required string

Tags: sql, regex, netezza

Good day

I've been trying to apply a specific exclusion in my regex_like function within Netezza SQL: **regexp_like(trim(upper(a.MRCH_NME)),'\bMAKRO\s?(?!DEBTORS)','i')**

Unfortunately I can't get the expression to exclude the "DEBTORS". Would anyone be able to assist me in finding my mistake?

Thank you.

Comment: Please show us sample data, including both positive and negative cases.

Comment: Hi Tim please see a few samples below: MAKRO AMANZIMTOTI, 346733 MAKRO LI, C#MAKRO STRUBENS VALLE, MAKRO DEBTORS WOODME

Comment: Edit your _question_ please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one quick fix to your pattern:

```
\bMAKRO\s(?!DEBTORS)
```

Code:

```
regexp_like(trim(upper(a.MRCH_NME)),'\bMAKRO\s(?!DEBTORS)','i')
```

The reason your current pattern is allowing `MAKRO DEBTORS WOODME` to pass is that it can take the `\s` as optional, then assert that `DEBTORS` does not immediately follow `MAKRO`.

### Demo

**Edit:**

You could also rewrite your negative lookahead slightly to this:

```
\bMAKRO(?!\s?DEBTORS)
```

Comment: I see, thank you kindly Tim. I really appreciate your assistance.

Comment: @Atlas_Apple Does this fix your problem?  I can't test in Netezza.

Comment: Hi Tim, yes it does indeed fix my problem. Thank you